# Compound index + regexp in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing

I am trying to solve a simple problem using complex mongoDB indexes. I have a `events` collection, and a `participants` collections. The documents in the `participants` collection  have a `searchable_keywords` field which is an Array.

I have the following compound index on my `guests` collection :

```
event_id_1_searchable_keywords_1
```

Appart from that I have a simple index `event_id` field on the `guests`collection.

When I run the following query :

```
eventId = db.events.findOne()["_id"];
db.guests.find({"event_id": eventId, "searchable_keywords": "engineer"}).explain()
```

I can see that the right index is being used.

The problem is when I run it using a regex search :

```
db.guests.find({"event_id": eventId, "searchable_keywords": /^engin/}).explain(true)
```

Here is the result :

```
{
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor event_id_1",
  "isMultiKey" : false,
  "n" : 0,
  "nscannedObjects" : 11,
  "nscanned" : 11,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 40,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 48,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 0,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 1,
  "indexBounds" : {
    "event_id" : [
        [
            ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a"),
            ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a")
        ]
    ]
},
"allPlans" : [
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor event_id_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 11,
        "nscanned" : 11,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "event_id" : [
                [
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a"),
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a")
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor deleted_at_1_event_id_1_updated_at_1_created_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 11,
        "nscanned" : 11,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "deleted_at" : [
                [
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            ],
            "event_id" : [
                [
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a"),
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a")
                ]
            ],
            "updated_at" : [
                [
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "created_at" : [
                [
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor event_id_1_searchable_keywords_1_created_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 13,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "event_id" : [
                [
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a"),
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a")
                ]
            ],
            "searchable_keywords" : [
                [
                    "",
                    {

                    }
                ],
                [
                    /engin/,
                    /engin/
                ]
            ],
            "created_at" : [
                [
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor deleted_at_1_event_id_1_searchable_keywords_1_created_at_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 9,
        "nscanned" : 13,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "deleted_at" : [
                [
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            ],
            "event_id" : [
                [
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a"),
                    ObjectId("532c5a5887512e567a00067a")
                ]
            ],
            "searchable_keywords" : [
                [
                    "",
                    {

                    }
                ],
                [
                    /engin/,
                    /engin/
                ]
            ],
            "created_at" : [
                [
                    {
                        "$maxElement" : 1
                    },
                    {
                        "$minElement" : 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"server" : "Romains-MacBook-Pro-2.local:27017",
"filterSet" : false,
"stats" : {
    "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
    "works" : 13,
    "yields" : 0,
    "unyields" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "advanced" : 0,
    "needTime" : 11,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "type" : "FETCH",
            "works" : 12,
            "yields" : 0,
            "unyields" : 0,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 11,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "forcedFetches" : 0,
            "matchTested" : 0,
            "children" : [
                {
                    "type" : "IXSCAN",
                    "works" : 11,
                    "yields" : 0,
                    "unyields" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "advanced" : 11,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : "{ event_id: 1 }",
                    "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['event_id']: [ObjectId('532c5a5887512e567a00067a'), ObjectId('532c5a5887512e567a00067a')]",
                    "isMultiKey" : 0,
                    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0,
                    "keysExamined" : 11,
                    "children" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Is it actually possible to perform a regex search in MongodDB on a compound index ?**

Comment: The answer to "Is it actually possible to perform a regex search in MongoDB on a compound index" is Yes (I set up a quick test with MongoDB 2.6.3 to be sure). Given your simple index is a proper subset of the compound index, you actually do not need to have both so you can drop the `{event_id:1}` index (it just adds overhead).

Comment: I suspect the reason the compound index may *not* be chosen when you are explaining the query is based on the data; it's possible that when the [query optimizer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) compares candidate query plans, the first index happens to return results faster for these values. Have you tried with different values for `eventId` and `searchable_keywords`? If you want to dig a bit further, can you post the results of `explain(true)` for this query from the `mongo` shell? That will show details on the query plans evaluation (rather than just the winning plan).

Comment: Also, what interface are you using to `explain()` the queries .. I notice you are using `where()` rather than `find()`?

Comment: Hi, I am actually using mongoid but I reproduced the issue on mongo shell. I will update my post right away, thanks.

Comment: @Stennie, I did not know the query optimizer was based on data. I actually found a slow query in a production db and tried to reproduce it in developement, and in both cases the intended index had not been used.

Comment: The MongoDB [Query Optimizer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) does [periodic evaluation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#query-plan-revision) of candidate plans for a given query shape and caches the result based on the plan that produces more results for less work. When you run `explain()` you are forcing a query plan comparison, so the timing here is indicative of the relative plan performance (but your queries on average will run much faster using the cached plan). I can tell you're using 2.6 from the explain, but what specific 2.6.x version are you using?

Comment: FYI, if you want to force MongoDB to choose a specific index for a query (i.e. to get more detailed stats from an explain) you can use the [`hint()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) option with an index name. Generally you only want to this for testing, as you may be forcing MongoDB to choose a poorer index. It's better to understand why an index other than the expected one is being chosen. Can you add the output of: `hint('event_id_1_searchable_keywords_1_created_at_-1').explain(true).stats` for comparison?

Comment: I am using 2.6.1 on my laptop, but prod servers are still running 2.4.  I will have to upgrade my indexes in production because the one I want is actually not available ... Thank you for this information. I think you can just answer this question. This is how it works right? The two precious things I learnt from your comments are the "Yes" answer and the periodic evaluation stuff. Thank you again

Comment: The query planner has been refactored between 2.4 and 2.6 so results may differ; you should definitely upgrade to latest 2.6 (currently 2.6.3, but 2.6.4 will be out soon) on your laptop/dev environment as there have a number of bug fixes & improvements. Would be worth watching one of the presentations on [Indexing & Query Optimization](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/indexing-and-query-optimization-0). I'll sum up with an answer based on our discussion here :)